# Bash script won't write to a file

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash.
Following script don't work, it always gives an error "find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Operation denied ".
I just wanted to get some basic info.
If i delete the part with find, save, run, than nothing happens.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
DefDir="/"
file="data.txt"
cd $DefDir
find . > $file
echo UPTIME:\n > $file
uptime >> $file
echo ENV:\n >> $file
env >> $file
echo Finished
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` is telling you that it's unable to enter that directory. There are two simple things you can do:

Add the error to the file:

```
find . > "$file" 2>&1
```

Ignore the error:

```
find . > "$file" 2> /dev/null
```

`gvfs` is a Gnome Virtual File System directory for letting a user browse network file systems and such, and is only accessible by its owner (not even as root).

Comment: Thanks. Now i don't have any error, but when i run it, it doesn't create $file.

Comment: What does `ls -l /data.txt` say?

Comment: Oh, im sorry, i searched for that file from where i executed that script, not in /